# How to center everything in jumbotron using twbs:bootstrap in Meteor

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I've been doing this for hours trying all the ways and I can't get these buttons to move.

I'm not sure how to override the CSS to do any margin tricks.

All I need is for everything in the jumbotron, text and button group, to be perfectly center.

```
<template name="Jumbotron">
<div class="jumbotron center">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>Get Started Now</p>
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
        </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the display property to inline-block for the `btn-toolbar` class.

See Example Snippets.

```css
.btn-toolbar.meteor-btn-toolbar,
.btn-toolbar.meteor-btn-toolbar2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  <p>Get Started Now</p>
  <div class="btn-toolbar meteor-btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..."> <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn More</a>
      <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn More</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  <p>Get Started Now</p>
  <div class="btn-toolbar meteor-btn-toolbar2"> <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've added that and now it looks the way I want it. Ideally I'd want them spaced out a little; what's a good way to add space between the buttons in a button toolbar?

Comment: Did you open the Snippet up so it's Full page? There are two examples and the second one has the buttons with space setting them apart. Is that what you mean?